# Finding the limit of a function

Tags: physics, code-review, modeling

I have the following code:

```
Ud = (11/10); 
Uin = 15*Sqrt[2]; 
Rb = (15/(2*10^(-3)*(29812/10^3))); 
c = (10000*10^(-6) + (22/10)*10^(-6));

y[fin_] = 2*fin*(2*T*Ud - ((Ud)/(fin)) + ((Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T])/(2*Pi*fin)) 
  + c*Rb*(2*Ud - Uin)*(Exp[-((T)/(c*Rb))] - 1));

Teqn[fin_] = Abs[Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T - (Pi/2)]] - 2*Ud 
  == (Uin - 2*Ud)*Exp[-T/(c*Rb)];

Tsol[fin_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[Teqn[fin], {T, 1/(4*fin), 1/(2*fin)}]; 

ListPlot[Table[{fin, y[fin] /. Tsol[fin]}, {fin, 10^(-5), 10000, 10}]]
```

How can I improve my code so that I can find:

$$\lim_{f_{in}\to\infty}y[fin]=\space\text{?}$$

Comment: `Collect[ y[fin] , fin]` shows you the structure of your function. There is a linear term `O[fin]`, so the limit doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, then it is necessary to calculate $y(x,T(x))$ for very large values of $x$. In this case, the code is

```
Ud = (11/10); Uin = 
 15*Sqrt[2]; Rb = (15/(2*10^(-3)*(29812/
       10^3))); c = (10000*10^(-6) + (22/10)*10^(-6));
y[fin_, T_] := 
  2*fin*(2*T*Ud - ((Ud)/(fin)) + ((Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T])/(2*Pi*fin)) + 
     c*Rb*(2*Ud - Uin)*(Exp[-((T)/(c*Rb))] - 1));
Teqn[fin_] = 
  Abs[Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T - (Pi/2)]] - 2*Ud == (Uin - 2*Ud)*
    Exp[-T/(c*Rb)];
T[fin_] := 
 T /. FindRoot[Teqn[fin], {T, 1/(4*fin), 1/(2*fin)}]; LogLogPlot[
 y[fin, T[fin]], {fin, 10^-5, 10^10}]
```

[image: Fig1]